# Intercept an exception being caught

Tags: java

Too much caffeine led to this. Yeah, you can actually catch it, but jokes aside.

```
public class GreasedUpDeafGuy extends RuntimeException {

    public GreasedUpDeafGuy() {
        super("You Can't Catch Me!");
    }

    @Override
    public void printStackTrace() {
        throw this;
    }
}
```

Purely as a thought experiment, is there some way to hook in to the 'catch' ?

```
try {
    throw new GreasedUpDeafGuy(); // This line itself is creepy
}
catch(GreasedUpDeafGuy e) {} // <-- How could one hook in to this call?
```

such that a devious developer could keep throwing this exception on? A friend suggested that the stack building could be the place to intercept but we can't figure out how. One assumes that Java protects itself against such idiocy, but I aim to be the biggest idiot I can be.

I'm not suggesting that the Exception class itself can do this. None of the methods in the exception are called when 'catch' is invoked.

We have to go deeper.

Comment: Are you talking about catching a *RuntimeException*?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `is there some way to hook in to the catch(GreasedUpDeafGuy e)`? The exception will be rethrown when `e.printStacktrace()` is called, not when it's caught...

Comment: You mean you want to keep this exception being thrown no matter how many `catch` blocks catch it? That's not possible. Also you can't rely on people calling `printStackTrace`.

Comment: Yes. I know it can be caught. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to actually throw the exception WHEN it is caught.

Comment: Since you cannot rely on that catch block calling any of the exception's methods,  there is no place you can intercept.

Comment: I'm thinking much bigger. Trying to figure out where/how the JVM would have to be hacked in order to intercept 'catch' calls.

Answer (score -1):

wrap it all up in another try catch block like :

```
try
{

try
{
     // more caffeine stuff
}catch(GreasedUpDeafGuy inner){inner.printStackTrace();}
}catch(GreasedUpDeafGuy outter){
 for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : outter.getStackTrace()) {
            System.out.println(stackTraceElement.toString());
        }}
```

and if it seems like a lot put in a method that only be used in catch block with this exception .

but if you really want to make the exception to be caughted twice throw the out side exception in the constructor so you want rely on just a method.

Comment: But this does not keep on throwing the exception. It re-throws itself once, but that's it. And what is that loop about the stacktracelements supposed to do? And throwing an Exception in it's own constructor is not helping at this requirement because you are throwing it at the Exception's creation time, not the catching time.

Comment: i meant another type of exception like throw a runtime or an implemetation of it @f1sh + the stack trace loop is just about printing the stack trace without the ```printStackTrace()``` method .

Comment: but how is that implementing an exception that keeps throwing itself no matter how you try to catch it?

Comment: I see where you're going @alovelyperson but I'm wondering if there's a way to throw the exception when it's caught, regardless of the catch code.

Comment: to do so you need a method that is excuted y the JVM when using ```catch``` and as far as i know thier is no such thing .